# Error while running a python file

Tags: python

I am getting a error while running it. The Error is :

```
File "binary_Light.py", 
           model_url^=project page

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binary_light.py", line 8, in <module>
    from brisa.upnp.device import Device, Service
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/brisa/upnp/device/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from brisa.upnp.device.device import Device
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/brisa/upnp/device/device.py", line 10, in <module>
    from brisa.core import log, config, webserver, network
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/brisa/core/webserver.py", line 39, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Network is down.')
RuntimeError: Network is down

Invalid syntax
```

It is pointing error ar url.

```
from brisa.core.reactors import install_default_reactor
reactor = install_default_reactor()
print reactor

import os

from brisa.upnp.device import Device, Service
from brisa.upnp.device.service import StateVariable


class SwitchPower(Service):

    def __init__(self):
        Service.__init__(self,
                         'SwitchPower',
                         'urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SwitchPower:1',
                         '',
                         os.getcwd() + '/SwitchPower-scpd.xml')
        self.target = False
        self.status = False


    def SetTarget(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.target = kwargs['NewTargetValue']
        self.status = self.target
        self.set_state_variable('Status', self.target)
        print 'Light switched ', {'1': 'on', '0': 'off'}.get(self.target, None)
        return {}

    def GetTarget(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'RetTargetValue': self.target}

    def soap_GetStatus(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'ResultStatus': self.status}


class BinaryLight(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.server_name = 'Binary Light Device'
        self.device = None
    def _create_device(self):
        project_page = 'https://garage.maemo.org/projects/brisa'
        self.device = Device('urn:schemas=upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1',
                            self.server_name,
                            manufacturer = 'Ankit',
                            model_name = 'Binary Light Device',
                            model_description = 'Test Device',
                            model_number = '1.0',
                            model_url= project_page)
    def _add_service(self):
        switch = SwitchPower()
        self.device.add_service(switch)
    def start(self):
        self._create_device()
        self._add_services()
        self.device.start()
        reactor.add_after_stop_func(self.device.stop)
        reactor.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = BinaryLight()
    device.start()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a comma missing at the end of `model_number = '1.0'`.

```
model_name = 'Binary Light Device',
model_description = 'Test Device',
model_number = '1.0'               <-
model_url= project_page)
```

Comment: thanks....after removing it, I am getting a run time error which is same as my other question that I posted a little earlier. Do I need to put the question again, or directly modify that?

Comment: @user600790 If someone can help you on this problem, he will do it on the existing question.

Comment: I edited this question and also added error which I am getting. Please see and let me know my mistake.

Comment: I know, there is a problem with Network. But what kind of problem it is?? What Network it can be??

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a comma:

```
model_description = 'Test Device',
model_number = '1.0',   # <- here
model_url= project_page)
```

Comment: I edited this question and also added error which I am getting now. Please see and let me know my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

there should be comma after the line `model_number = '1.0'`